# Onde o SQL Developer salva o arquivo do BD?

Tags: oracle, sqldeveloper

Onde os bancos que eu crio no SQL Developer ficam salvos ? 
Eu gostaria de poder escolher o local/pasta para salvar o Banco, mais não sei onde ele esta salvando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente, o oracle salva os dados de seus *schemas* dentro de `tablespaces`, das quais dentro ficam os `datafiles`, esse que são arquivos físicos, e as vezes compartilhados entre *schemas*.

Para saber qual `tablespace` seu *schema* esta utilizando, pode executar o script:

```
SELECT owner,tablespace_name
  FROM dba_segments
 WHERE owner = 'SEUSCHEMA'
 GROUP BY tablespace_name,owner
```

Para saber qual é o `datafile`:

```
SELECT ddf.file_name
  FROM sys.dba_data_files ddf
 WHERE ddf.tablespace_name = 'NOME_TABLESPACE'
```

Terá um retorno parecido com:

> /u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/nome_do_datafile.dbf

---

Para escolher o local onde salvar, você terá que ver os diretorios que
tem disponíveis no Oracle:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_directories
```

para criar um novo diretorio no oracle, basta usar o script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY NOMEDOMEUDIRETORIO AS '/caminho/pasta/meubanco';
```

Então na hora de criar seu banco, basta escolher seu novo diretório.