# Arquivo físico banco Oracle

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Estou tendo o mesmo problema dessa pergunta : [Onde o SQL Developer salva o arquivo do BD?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193087/onde-o-sql-developer-salva-o-arquivo-do-bd)  mais como eu não tenho pontos para comentar, e perguntar lá mesmo, inicie um novo "tópico".

Eu tentei fazer do modo que a resposta diz, porém, como eu sou um usuário inciante em Oracle, acredito estar fazendo errado.

```
SELECT owner,tablespace_name
  FROM dba_segments
 WHERE owner = 'SEUSCHEMA'
 GROUP BY tablespace_name,owner
Para saber qual é o datafile:

SELECT ddf.file_name
  FROM sys.dba_data_files ddf
 WHERE ddf.tablespace_name = 'NOME_TABLESPACE'
```

se eu executar esses trechos na ferramenta (SQLDeveloper), ele me retorna colunas vazias. Eu acredito que eu deva substituir `WHERE owner =` **'SEUSCHEMA'**  e `WHERE ddf.tablespace_name =` **'NOME_TABLESPACE'**, por algum nome que eu defini em algum momento no banco, mais, eu não sei pelo o que substituir, eu dei uma lida na documentação para entender, porém não me deixou claro o que fazer.

**Para explicitar o meu problema, o que eu quero fazer, é poder escolher onde salvar o aquivo do BD, ou pelo menos, encontrá-lo e copiar o arquivo do banco de dados, para que eu possa coloca - lo na pasta da minha aplicação JAVA**.

Comment: Não é o SQL Developer que salva o arquivo, mas o próprio Oracle. Acho que você não entendeu como funciona o SGBD, o Oracle não tem um arquivo só que vc possa embutir na aplicação, ele separa os dados em vários arquivos gerenciados pelo banco, pra serem acessador pela rede, não para serem transportados.

Comment: Só complementando: se vc precisa de um banco que você possa distribuir com a aplicação, você precisa pesquisar por DB's como H2, Firebird, LocalDB, SQLite.

Comment: @JúlioNeto então nenhuma versão do Oracle vai dar pra distribuir com a aplicação ?

Comment: Eu não conheço nenhuma versão "Embedded" do Oracle, sei que o LocalDB é uma versão embedded do SQL Server, mas do Oracle nunca ouvi falar de algo nessa linha.